# Converting a string pulled from the internet into a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I am making a program that scrapes the internet and populates a class with all of the information I'm scraping for. I have a `DateTime` property that needs to be populated from the string I am pulling in. The string that comes in looks like this :`9:53a ET 08/13/18`.

I have tried using `DateTime.ParseExact()` to try and convert this string into a DateTime, using the following format string: `"h:mmt ET mm/dd/yy"`

So the call looks like this: `var lastTime = DateTime.ParseExact(listValue[0].InnerText, format, provider);`

Where `InnerText` is just the text that I am trying to convert, `Format` is the string I specified above, and the `provider` is `en-US`.

I get the following exception when trying to execute this line: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

How would I format this string to convert it to a DateTime correctly?

Comment: mm is minutes.  Try MM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems. First of all, as pointed out by @ChrisCudmore, you need to use `MM` for the month, not `mm`. Second of all, `DateTime.Parse()` will expect the AM/PM designator to be in upper case, so you need to upper-case it. Here is an example:

```
string strDate = "9:53a ET 08/13/18";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate.ToUpper(), "h:mmt ET MM/dd/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This should work with the example string date you provided!

Comment: ToUpper worked correctly. Didn't even realize that the AM/PM designation was looking for an upper case and not lower. Thanks.

Comment: Use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or it will throw a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` if you aren't using the english culture in the user system.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9:53a ET 08/13/18".ToUpper(), "h:mmt ET MM/dd/yy", null)
```

Returns a correctly parsed date. `a` is not recognized as a AM/PM identifier because it is lowercase (hence the `toUpper`), and `mm/dd/yy` should be `MM/dd/yy` since `mm` (lowercase is minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that will throw you off here is the `a` and `p` designation.  <s>This isn't officially supported through the date time formats.</s> (**SEE EDIT**)  I don't know if this is the best performing solution but you could use `TryParseExact()` to account for the `a` and `p`.  I made a static method that solves your issue:

```
public static DateTime? CustomParse(string dateString)
{
    DateTime date;

    //Hard code the 'a' in the parse string
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "h:mma ET MM/dd/yy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        return date;
    }
    //'a' wasnt in the right position, try the 'p'
    else if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "h:mmp ET MM/dd/yy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        //Adding 12 hours to make it "PM" to the DateTime object
        date = date.AddHours(12);
        return date;
    }               

    // Could not parse, return null
    return null;
}
```

Also, Remember to use `MM` instead of `mm`, `mm` is minutes not months.

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y0gcst)

**EDIT** Saw the other answers, I was way off thinking `a` and `p` alone were not recognized.  The `ToUpper()` trick is genius, **do not use mine!**